# DEAP eaSimple algorithm with odd number of individuals

Tags: python, deap

The [documentation for the eaSimple algorithm](https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/algo.html#deap.algorithms.varAnd) states that parents are divided into pairs of consecutive individuals, and each pair generates two offspring.

> First, the parental population Pp is duplicated using the
>   toolbox.clone() method and the result is put into the offspring
>   population Po. A first loop over Po is executed to mate pairs of
>   consecutive individuals. According to the crossover probability cxpb,
>   the individuals xi and xi+1 are mated using the toolbox.mate() method.
>   The resulting children yi and yi+1 replace their respective parents in
>   Po.

How is the last individual from a population with an odd number of individuals handled? Is it never mated with another individual and only mutated?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at [the code](https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/deap/algorithms.py), there is a loop over the population which pairs up individuals for crossover in `varAnd`:

```py
for i in range(1, len(offspring), 2):
```

This means that if there is an odd number of individuals, one individual will never mated.

The loop for mutation is

```py
for i in range(len(offspring)):
```

so every individual will be mutated.

Conclusion: indeed, the last individual in a population with an odd number of individuals may be mutated but will never be used for crossover.